# SQL- Is this a multi step line of code...add column than add data for each row ONLY for that particular column

Tags: sql-server

There is a table below and further below is the question. Is this a multi-line code with parenthesis to use for this? This is for a business analyst assignment...its the first time im using sql(I've used python, js, html, css self-taught back when i was trying to be a web developer)

SQL Queries

Table Name: TRADES

```
DATE    FIRM    SYMBOL  SIDE    QUANTITY    PRICE
2/3/2014    1ABC    A123    B   200         41
2/4/2014    2BCD    B234    B   600         60
2/7/2014    1ABC    C345    S   600         70
2/10/2014   3CDE    C345    S   600         70
2/12/2014   4DEF    B234    B   200         62
2/14/2014   3CDE    B234    B   300         61
2/21/2014   1ABC    A123    B   300         40
2/24/2014   1ABC    A123    S   300         30
2/25/2014   4DEF    C345    B   2100        71
2/27/2014   CDE B234    S   1100            63
```

Q3. Your business user asks you to show them a table that includes the number of trades for each firm and symbol combination in the data table above. Please write the SQL query you would use to query TRADES table to get below result

```
FIRM    SYMBOL  NO_TRADES
1ABC    A123    3
2BCD    B234    1
1ABC    C345    1
3CDE    C345    1
4DEF    B234    1
3CDE    B234    1
4DEF    C345    1
CDE B234    1
```

Comment: How will you learn if you don't try. Did you consider reviewing your recent notes or class materials which should have covered the topics and functionality you need to use to answer the question? And your desired output seems to be incorrect - did you add the typo / error?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like simple aggregation:

```
select firm, symbol, count(*) no_trades
from mytable
group by firm, symbol
order by no_trades desc, symbol
```

Comment: grouping does not guarantee order - don't assume.

Comment: @SMor: well there was not explicit requirement about ordering the results in the question. But ok, I added an `order by` clause.